# Changes of Code Coverage in SonarQube 6.2

Tags: junit, sonarqube, code-coverage, integration-testing

I have a problem: I used to use SonarQube version 5.1 where I had JUnit and Integration tests' code coverage set up. Both of these were represented by three items in SonarQube (coverage, it_coverage, overall_coverage - the previous two merged).

Since the 6.2 version, the coverage and it_coverage shouldn't be available anymore, there is supposed to have just an item called coverage which is the value of the item overall_coverage of previous versions (if report paths to jaccoco are set up correctly for jUnit reports and integration tests reports), everything should work well.

My question is, how can I recognize that the integration tests are included in the coverage cause, I don't have any indicator which makes me know that these tests were part of the analysis, cause I still see just the number of unit tests where the Jameleon ones are not listed in.

Comment: Out of curiosity @Miroslav, why do you care?

Comment: I developed a tool which queries the rest Api of SonarQuebe and stores these 3 items (coverage, it_coverage, overall_coverage) to provide data history of the code coverage to measure the efficiency of the testing processes (testers - it_coverage, programmers - jUnit coverage).

Answer (score 1):

There is no visual way in SonarQube to be sure that your IT coverage has been taken into account.

You can probably look at the analysis logs to verify that the reports are found (if not, you will get a warning message).

If you want to be sure, you can also run an analysis without specifying the IT report and see if there's a difference or not.

Comment: Thanks Fabrice, I've already tried to make a comparison, I wanted to do a double check, as you mentioned above, the log can be used for this purpose. Don't you know which file of the logs I should be looking for this information. I haven't found anything what is related to the reports in the log files. I might need to use a deeper level of logging.